# AngularJS Scope - Chrome App

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, google-chrome-app

Kind of new to Angular JS which I'm using to create a Chrome app.

Anyone know how I can access `chillax.breakInterval` (and other properties of 'chillax') within the `chrome.storage.sync.get` callback function?

```
angular.module('ChillaxApp', [])
    .controller("ChillaxController", function () {

    var chillax = this;

    chillax.init = function() {
        var settings = {};

        settings["enabled"] = "";
        settings["reminderInterval"] = "";
        settings["breakInterval"] = "";
        settings["sound"] = "";

        chrome.storage.sync.get(settings, function(obj) {
            // Setting these variables here aren't available within the controller
            chillax.reminderInterval = obj["reminderInterval"];
            chillax.breakInterval = obj["breakInterval"];
            chillax.sound = obj["sound"];
        });
    };
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `settings.reminderInterval` not `chillax.reminderInterval` and etc.?

Comment: `console.log("Obj loaded: " + obj["reminderInterval"]); // Outputs 6
console.log("Settings loaded: " + settings["reminderInterval"]); // Outputs nothing`

Comment: Other end of the equation there `chillax.reminderInterval = obj["reminderInterval"];` becomes `settings.reminderInterval = obj["reminderInterval"];`

Comment: Since the function in the `chrome.storage.sync.get` is a callback modifying the `settings` object doesn't help. I need the value to be assigned to `chillax.reminderInterval`.